# Bash Script escape command string to use variable as filename

Tags: bash, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-speech

How do I escape the string to use a variable for the filename within the following script? Am I even getting the variable in a proper manner?

The scenario is I have a few dozen small flac files of voice messages. They need to be sent with the gcloud command/url individually and a return is sent and this return output is set as a variable. After I get the return response I need to send the same file and the return response to a database using the json file schema.

**Edited: I have tried escaping by adding/wrapping in single quotes, double quotes and backticks. all return errors and all return errors show the url containing "$i" rather than a filename.flac.**

When I try without escaping the string I get this error:

When I do it without escaping I get this:

```
add2.sh: line 4: syntax error near unexpected token `sudo'
add2.sh: line 4: `      sudo gcloud ml speech recognize `/var/www/html/library/422980-2560-WIN/$i --language-code='en-US' >STT.txt`'
```

Here is the script:

```
#!/bin/bash
    cd /var/www/html/library/422980-2560-WIN
    for i in *.flac;
        sudo gcloud ml speech recognize `/var/www/html/library/422980-2560-WIN/"$i" --language-code='en-US' >STT.txt`
    done
    STT=`grep -Po '"transcript": *\K"[^"]*"' STT.txt | cut -d '"' -f2`
    echo $STT
    sudo gsutil cp /var/www/html/library/422980-2560-WIN/"$i".flac gs://422980
    #rm -i -f -- /var/www/html/library/422980-2560-WIN/*.flac
    sudo /usr/local/fuego --credentials /home/repeater/medialunaauth01-280236ff5e5f.json add 422980 '
    {
            "bucketObject": "https://storage.cloud.google.com/$i",
            "fileDay": "filedaytest33",
            "fileMonth": "filemonttest33",
            "fileName": "filenametest33",
            "fileTime": "filetimetest33",
            "fileYear": "fileyeartest33",
            "liveOnline": "0",
            "qCChecked": "0",
            "speechToText":"'"$STT"'",
            "transcribedData": "",
    }'
```

Comment: If you're trying to create or parse JSON in bash, use the `jq` utility rather than grepping strings.

Comment: Filenames don't need any escaping. What problem are you having?

Comment: You're overwriting the `STT.txt` file each time through the `for` loop, so when you assign to `STT` it will just get the value from the last file.

Comment: Do you really have backticks around the argument after `recognize`? Are the `flac` files executable files?

Comment: Normally I would use jq, but I am confident that nothing in the return string will break the json, I thought if that was the case it would be ok? Did I misunderstand this?

Comment: I'm not suggesting it as a solution to the problem, just as a general recommendation.

Comment: Did you mean to have the code beginning with `STT=` inside the loop?

Comment: You're missing the `do` keyword that's required as part of the `for` loop syntax: `for i in *.flac; do`

Comment: The syntax error message shows the command without variables replaced. It has nothing to do with escaping.

Comment: Thank you for all the feedback. I will go through each bit slowly and try to rewrite it before coming back with more questions... The reason it is so messed up is because I am not good at scripting and got little pieces of functionality bit by bit and now I am trying to bring it all together into a single script. The issue is all the "testing" was successful on just a single file in the directory, scaling it is proving to be too much for me haha

Comment: Two recommendations: Paste your script into shellcheck.net to check the syntax, and use `set -x` at the beginning to make it show a trace of all commands, with variables substituted.